# DB2 query is throwing an error

Tags: db2

**My query :**
 FETCH NEXT  FROM LOAD_CUR

INTO JOBSTREAM_MODULE_ID,

TABLENAME,

COL_NAME

END;

END IF;

END

**Error**
I am getting the below error:
An unexpected token "FROM" was found following " 
 FETCH NEXT".  Expected tokens may include:  ".".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.18.60

Comment: show all your code...what platform and version of DB2?

Comment: Code is too long

Comment: Data Studio-4.1.2

Comment: That is neither the platform nor the version of DB2

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to use the FETCH FROM cursor-name in embedded-SQL (there is no FETCH NEXT statement at SQL level in Db2).  See [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000954.html).

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i was trying to do....is there any other alternative to FETCH NEXT

Comment: Why do you think that the Db2 FETCH statement in embedded-SQL is not what you want?